# What is going on here? $(-1<x^2<3 \Leftrightarrow -\sqrt{3} < x < \sqrt{3})$?

Tags: inequality, radicals

Can someone explain how is this possible ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSII3.png))? Or is it wrong?
Shouldn't it be $(-1<x^2<3 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{-1} < x < \sqrt{3})$?

Comment: You can't type the contents of that image?

Comment: I'm sorry. I just corrected it

Comment: $-1<x^2$ is an obvious statement anyway.

Comment: Please see the updated image.

Comment: What troubles you in that derivation?

Comment: In your edit you showed that if $-1<x^2<3$ then $$\sqrt{-1}<x<\sqrt{3}?$$ Are you sure?

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm weak in Math. Can you tell me why I'm wrong?

Comment: $-1<x^2<3 \implies 0 \le x^2 < 3 \implies 0 \le |x| < \sqrt 3 \implies -\sqrt 3 \le x \le \sqrt 3$

Comment: Sir, taking square roots to both both sides of the inequality $a<b$ holds if $a\geq 0$. In your case, $-1<x^2$, so taking square root to both sides is not allowed.

Comment: However, if $x^2<3$ then taking square root is allowed. We get $\sqrt{x^2}<\sqrt{3}$. By definition, $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. With this, we get $|x|<\sqrt{3}$ which is equivalent to $-\sqrt{3}<x<\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implicit assumption in your example is that $f$ is a real-valued function of real variable.  The alternative is to assume that you are working with complex numbers, but that isn't the case here.  The obvious clue is that numbers are compared with $<$.  If we were working with complex numbers, we would have to specify what we mean by $a < b$.

If $x$ is a real number, $x^2$ is greater than or equal to $0$.  Therefore $x^2 > -1$ is always true and can be ignored.  We are left with $x^2 < 3$.  Every $x$ such that $-\sqrt{3} < x < \sqrt{x}$ is such that $x^2 < 3$, which is what the final line of the derivation shows.  Moreover, every real number $x$ such that either $x \leq -\sqrt{3}$ or $x \geq \sqrt{3}$ is such that $x^2 \geq 3$.  Hence

$$ -\sqrt{3} < x < \sqrt{3} $$

describes all values of $x$ for which $|f(x)| < 1$ holds.